# Datepart() function not converting into bigint

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion, integer, bigint

I am trying a simple select operation

```
select datepart(year,AttendanceTimeIn)*100000000  from TV_AttendanceTable
```

but getting the following error:

*Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.*

I have tried to typecast it into BigInt as well but no luck, same error appears.

```
select CONVERT(BIGINT, datepart(year,AttendanceTimeIn)*100000000)  from TV_AttendanceTable
```

Note: AttendanceTimeIn column is a datetime type column in my SQL table.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (`datetime`, `datepart` and `convert` are all product specific functions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting *after* the multiplication.  That is too late.  You need to convert one of the values *before* the multiplication:

```
CONVERT(BIGINT, datepart(year, AttendanceTimeIn)) * 100000000
```

Or as I would write it:

```
CONVERT(BIGINT, year(AttendanceTimeIn)) * 100000000
```